# Remove Data by multiple ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a student management. I can insert,update and delete students. But deleting is only possible with one ID and I want to delete a student by specifying two IDs. What do I need to add or change?

```
    public void DeleteStudentByIDs(int ID1, int ID2)
{
    var student = context.TableStudent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id1 == ID1);
    context.TableStudent.Remove(student);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do the following if you want to delete two students at a time

```
var students = context.TableStudent.Where(x => x.id1 == ID1 ||x.id1 == ID2);
context.TableStudent.RemoveRange(students);
```

Or keep your code, just changing the lambda to `x.id1 == ID1 && x.id2 == ID2` in case you have a single student with two ids, where both has to match